# Does deleting a document from Firebase's Cloud Firestore delete any sub collections in that document?

Tags: firebase, swift4, ios11, google-cloud-firestore

Here is an example of how I am currently deleting documents:

```
let transactionsRef = db.collection(Globals.GroupsPath).document(Group.instance.getAll().id).collection(Globals.GroupTransactions)
let query = transactionsRef.whereField(Globals.TransactionCreator, isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
   guard error == nil else {
      print(error!.localizedDescription)
      callback(error)
      return
   }

   if let snapshot = snapshot {
      let batch = self.db.batch()
      for doc in snapshot.documents {
         batch.deleteDocument(doc.reference)
      }
      batch.commit()
      callback(nil)
   }
   // TODO: Create an error here and return it.
}
```

I noticed however that after doing this that in the Firestore database the document is greyed out but I can still click on it and view collections within that document and their data!

Do I need to manually delete each item from the sub collection before deleting the parent document or does it just take a while for the delete to complete? What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a document does not delete subcollections. You do need to manually delete all subcollections, as outlined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections) in the documentation. You will see that the documentation doesn't recommend deleting subcollections from the client because there are so many ways that could go wrong. It's labor-intensive for the client, may involve read and write permissions issues, etc. You'll want to use a server or serverless solution. So, for example, this is how deleting subcollections would work server-side with Node.js:

```
function deleteCollection(db, collectionPath, batchSize) {
     var collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath);
     var query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
    });
}

function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) {
query.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        // When there are no documents left, we are done
        if (snapshot.size == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Delete documents in a batch
        var batch = db.batch();
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            batch.delete(doc.ref);
        });

        return batch.commit().then(() => {
            return snapshot.size;
        });
    }).then((numDeleted) => {
        if (numDeleted === 0) {
            resolve();
            return;
        }

        // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
        // exploding the stack.
        process.nextTick(() => {
            deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
        });
    })
    .catch(reject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll look into using Firebase functions to do this.

Comment: @Jen Person, How can I delete a document which has nested subcollections in javascript? `firestore.collection(parentNd).doc(productTitle).delete().then(function() { }` is not working. This is the full node looks like `firestore.collection(parentNode).doc(productTitle).collection("categoryList").doc().set({}`